# Skewed Projector is Nonexpansive

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, projection

I read the book "Finite-Dimensional Variational Inequalities and Complementarity Problems I", and try to solve Exercise 1.8.16.

> 1.8.16. Let K be a closed convex set in $\Re^n$ and $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix of order $n$. Use (1.5.11) to show that the skewed projector is nonexpansive under the $A$-norm; i.e.,
> $\|P_{K,A}(u)-P_{K,A}(v)\|_A \leq \|u-v\|_A, \forall u,v\in\Re^n$,
> where $\|\cdot\|_A$ is a $A$-norm, e.g., $\|x\|_A=\sqrt{x^T Ax}$.

The inequality (1.5.11) is
$(P_{K,A}(v)-P_{K,A}(u))^T A(v-u) \geq (P_{K,A}(v)-P_{K,A}(u))^T A (P_{K,A}(v)-P_{K,A}(u))$

It does not seem difficult to show but I cannot find any way to solve this.

If someone already knows how to solve it, could you answer this question? Thank you.

Comment: In your statement of inequality 1.5.11, is there really meant to be a norm there?

Comment: Sorry, it my mistake. The left hand side is not norm but $(P_{K,A}(v)-P_{K,A}(u))$. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vectors $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, let
$$\langle x, y \rangle = y^\top A x.$$
As you may or may not know, this forms an inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Linearity in the first coordinate follows from basic properties of matrix multiplication. Similarly, symmetry follows from $A$ being symmetric, and basic properties of the transpose operator. Finally, positive-definiteness of the inner product corresponds precisely to the positive-definiteness of $A$.

Further, the canonical norm for this inner product, defined by $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$, is precisely the $A$-norm.

So, inequality 1.5.11 says
$$\langle v - u, P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\rangle \ge \|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A^2.$$
Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states,
$$\|v - u\|_A \cdot \|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A \ge \langle v - u, P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\rangle.$$
Therefore,
$$\|v - u\|_A \cdot \|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A \ge \|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A^2.$$
If $\|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A = 0$, then non-expansiveness holds trivially. If not, then $\|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A > 0$, so we can divide both sides by it, to get
$$\|v - u\|_A \ge \|P_{K, A}(v) - P_{K, A}(u)\|_A,$$
as required.

Comment: I appreciate your kind solution guide. I did not recognize that $\langle x, y\rangle= x^\top A y$ has the properties of the inner product on $\Re^n$. I want to push +1 but I do not have reputation point over 15, sorry.

Comment: No worries @Keith. I'm glad this was helpful.